# Upgraded Ionic app from Angular 4.1.3 to Angular 5 which caused "illegal constructor" error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I decided to update my Ionic 3.8.0 app which was using Angular 4.1.3 to Ionic 3.9.2 which is using Angular 5. After updating I tried to run the app in the browser but I keep getting an "illegal constructor" error message. What could be causing this error? If I need to provide more info please let me know

The error

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at _createClass (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10974:20)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10950:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10935:17)
    at _callFactory (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11001:28)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10953:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10935:17)
    at _callFactory (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11005:67)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10953:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10935:17)
    at _callFactory (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:11003:67)
```

app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp
{
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform,
              statusBar: StatusBar,
              splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              config: Config,
              keyboard: Keyboard,
              private storage: Storage,
              private authService: AuthServiceProvider, // This is causing the error
              device: Device,
              alerts: AlertServiceProvider
              )
  {
}
```

authServiceProvider.service.ts

```
  constructor(
              private http: HttpClient,
              private storage: Storage,
              private constants: GlobalConstants,
              private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService
  )
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
        "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.8.0",
        "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.15.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.14.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
        "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class is specified in _createClass (http://localhost:8101/build/vendor.js:10974:20)?